# Rails Render View If File Exists

Tags: ruby-on-rails, erb

I'm in the process of creating a modular Rails template based on the Device template. I have the main application layout:

**application.html.erb**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title><%= content_for?(:title) ? yield(:title) : "Rails Devise" %></title>
    <meta name="description" content="<%= content_for?(:description) ? yield(:description) : "Rails Devise" %>">
    <%= stylesheet_link_tag 'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
    <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
    <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
  </head>
  <body>
    <header>
      <%= render 'layouts/navigation' %>
    </header>
    <main role="main">
       <%= render 'layouts/messages' %>
       <%= yield %>
    </main>
    <footer>
       <% if File.exist?('layouts/footer') %>
          <%= render 'layouts/footer' %>
       <% end %>
    </footer>
  </body>
</html>
```

I have a footer template that I'd like to include if the file is present (which it may not be):

**_footer.html.erb**

```
<p class="text-muted">
  &copy; <%= Time.now.year.to_s %> All rights reserved
</p>
```

File.exist? isn't rendering the footer when it's there. How can I include the footer only if the template file exists?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try use `rescue nil` at the end of `render`.

`render nil` will show nothing.

`<%= render 'layouts/footer' rescue nil %>`

Hope it helps, cheers!

Comment: You should never do this. It will rescue every error and fail silently, leading to bugs that are hard to find.

Answer (score 7):

A better answer than `rescue` strategy or `Fail.exists?` strategy is to use `template_exists?`.

It's better because it uses **cache**.

```
<% if lookup_context.template_exists?('layouts/footer') %>
  <%= render 'layouts/footer'  %>
<% end %>
```

---

More info about [`template_exists?`](https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/LookupContext/ViewPaths/template_exists%3F)

Answer (score 4):

Don't use `rescue`, this can be very dangerous. Is better this way

```
<% if File.exists? Rails.root.join('app/views/layouts/footer.html.erb') %>
  <%= render 'layouts/footer'  %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: what about views in other locations in the view path?

Comment: @NickM then change this part `'app/views/layouts/footer.html.erb'` for wherever you want. Example: `'app/views/posts/details.html.erb'`

Comment: how bout template_exists?